# Accumulating Characters in Python

Tags: python

So I have this textfile, and in that file it goes like this... (just a bit of it)

```
"The truest love that ever heart
Felt at its kindled core
Did through each vein in quickened start
The tide of being pour
Her coming was my hope each day
Her parting was my pain
The chance that did her steps delay
Was ice in every vein
I dreamed it would be nameless bliss
As I loved loved to be
And to this object did I press
As blind as eagerly
But wide as pathless was the space
That lay our lives between
And dangerous as the foamy race
Of ocean surges green
And haunted as a robber path
Through wilderness or wood
For Might and Right and Woe and Wrath
Between our spirits stood
I dangers dared I hindrance scorned
I omens did defy
Whatever menaced harassed warned
I passed impetuous by
On sped my rainbow fast as light
I flew as in a dream
For glorious rose upon my sight
That child of Shower and Gleam"
```

Now, the calculate the length of words without the letter 'e' in each line of text. So in the first line it should have 4, then 5, then 17, etc.

My current code is

```
for line in open("textname.txt"):
  line_strip = line.strip()
  line_strip_split = line_strip.split()
  for word in line_strip_split:
    if "e" not in word:
     word_e = word


     print (len(word_e))
```

My explanation is: Strip each word from each other by removing spaces, so it becomes ['Felt','at','its','kindled','core'], etc. Then we split each word because we can regard it individually when removing words with 'e'?. So we want words without e, then print the length of the string.

HOWEVER, this separates each word into a different line by splitting then separating the string? So this doesn't add all the words together in each line but separates it, so the answer becomes "4 / 2 / 3"

Comment: If you don't get this question I am willing to explain more

Comment: I'm just trying to learn on grok by myself but I've come to an issue

Comment: I know we need a nested for loop but potentially an in-loop aggregation?

Comment: Add the length of each word that doesn't have `e` to something and then print it *after* you've looked at all words...?

Comment: where is you file new lines? can you post some of your files in suitable way ?

Comment: 0) for each line 1) split line, 2) set count to 0, 3) loop over words, 4) add length of word if it doesn't contain `e` to `count`, 5) print `count`

Comment: @Mehrdad-pedramfar i just edited it

Comment: @JonClements do i need to strip and split each line?

Comment: @D.Ronald well yeah... how else are you going to produce the counts for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for line in open("textname.txt"):
    line_strip = line.strip()
    line_strip_split = line_strip.split()
    words_with_no_e = []
    for word in line_strip_split:
        if "e" not in word:
            # Adding words without e to a new list
            words_with_no_e.append(word)
    # ''.join() will returns all the elements of array concatenated
    # len() will count the length
    print(len(''.join(words_with_no_e)))
```

It append all the words without `e` in into new list in each line, then concatenate all words then it prints length of it.

Comment: when you run it you get: "15
9
21
10
18
16
18
9
21
10
13
9
13
17
10
8
10
13
27
15
14
4
13
12
22
6
22
14"

Comment: :), the answer we're trying to get is "4
5
17
6
14
16
7
5
13
5
13
9
8
10
10
2
10
13
27
15
2
4
0
3
22
6
22
14"

Comment: if we follow what @Jon Clement said, i think we set count = 0 originally, then do like count += len(word) each time?? but I didn't get correct answer, or I might be confused what Jon said.

Comment: Wow! nice! so the append method added all the words together?

Comment: thanks alot! Can you just explain the last 2 lines :) MUCH APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: @D.Ronald No the append will add the words to new list, the `''.join()` will concatenate them.

Comment: @D.Ronald I added some comments to the answer for better understanding.